# NASM using expressions

Tags: nasm

In chapter 3.5 of the NASM manual, there are definitions for a bunch of expressions: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html

I can't seem to use those though. Arithmetic works;

```
db (10 / 5)
```

outputs a byte with value 2, as expected. But I cannot figure out how to use the other operators, like the > and ?:

```
db (10 % 4) > 0
```

should create a byte with value 1, but instead when I try to compile it, it gives me `error: comma expected after operand 1`. Same if I try to use the ?:

```
db (10 % 4) > 0 ? 10 : 20
```

same error.

How do I use these operators?

Comment: Make sure your NASM version is not something like 2.14.2 and is >= 2.15. I think 2.14.2 is the latest version for debian-based systems at least. You can check the version with `nasm -v` in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks @mediocrevegetable1, that was indeed the issue. After manually updating the binary, it works as expected.